# Click events not triggered in firefox (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, events

This code fine work in all browser, except firefox browser.
Event click don't work.

```
var marker = new RichMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( _latitude, _longitude ),
        map: map,
        draggable: draggableMarker,
        content: markerContent,
        flat: true
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {

    alert(this.position);

});
```

How I can fix that? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be line 615 of http://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/src/richmarker.js

```
 this.markerWrapper_.setCapture(true);
```

When you add a click-listener to a marker internally the click-event will be triggered when you click on the content of the marker. With the above line the click-event will fire for the wrapper of the content only(happens when a marker is draggable).

You'll need to modify the function `addDraggingListeners_`, set it to:

```
RichMarker.prototype.addDraggingListeners_ = function() {
  var that = this;
    this.draggingListeners_ = [
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'mousemove', function(e) {
        that.drag(e);
      }, true),
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'mouseup', function() {
        that.stopDrag();
      }, true)
    ];
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That was extremely helpful!